# Pstricks improper output

Tags: pstricks, circles, shapes

I recently started pstricks in LaTeX and tried to plot basic shapes using the 
`\put` command. I'm not getting the desired output. Here are the commands that I entered:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
   \begin{pspicture}(250,75)
      %For triangle
      \put(15,10){\line(1,0){50}}
      \put(65,10){\line(0,1){50}}
      \put(65,60){\line(-1,-1){50}}
      %For square
      \put(100,10){\line(0,1){50}}
      \put(100,10){\line(1,0){50}}
      \put(150,10){\line(0,1){50}}
      \put(100,60){\line(1,0){50}}
      %For circle
      \put(200,35){\circle{40}}
   \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output that I get. There is supposed to be a diagonal line in the first shape but it's very faint so it can't be seen and the circle is very tiny so it is not visible. No matter what I put as the radius, it is always tiny. And when I try to zoom in, it does so by like 300% and when I try to zoom out, it crashes.

I don't know what is wrong with this. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it makes no sense to use the picture commands together with PSTricks commands.
However, set the correct unit:

```
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1bp}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{pspicture}(250,75)
    %For triangle
```

This makes sense:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(250,75)
    %For triangle
    \pspolygon(15,10)(65,10)(65,60)
    %For square
    \psframe(100,10)(150,60)
    %For circle
    \pscircle(200,35){40}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The default unit is 1cm, which makes it easier to place objects.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.5cm}
    \begin{pspicture}(25,7.5)
    %For triangle
    \pspolygon(1.5,1.0)(6.5,1.0)(6.5,6.0)
    %For square
    \psframe(10,1)(15,6)
    %For circle
    \pscircle(20,3.5){4}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is detecting lots of errors. It says `!Undefined control sequence.\c@lor@to@ps->\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format\pspolygon(` and 11 more that start with `!Undefined control sequence`. Is this a problem with configuration?

Comment: Run it with xelatex or LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf